# How can I email all registered users?

Tags: 7, emails

A lot of similar questions show up in Google, but I can't find a solution for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for this, and send a tokenized email. I have it create jobs rather than sending everything all at once. But every year I sent an email to 18000 members.

Update: Sadly, token replacement (a key feature to do this successfully, unless you're sending the same message to everybody) seems to be broken right now in both 6.x-1.x and 7.x-3.x of VBO. See http://drupal.org/node/1348552)

The basic strategy:

- Create a view of users
- In D6, you make it a VBO view by changing the style; in D7 you do it by adding a "bulk operations" field.
- When configuring the style or the field, tell it you want to send an email (or tokenized email in D6; make sure you have token_actions enabled).
- Send the email. Use tokens in your email like

  - D6: [mail] and [user] - there are prompts to show you how
  - D7: [user:mail] and [user:name]. It's hard to figure out the right tokens for D7, but if you install and enable the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token) and then visit the admin->configure->system->actions and create an email action, you'll be prompted with the available options.

Things you'll want to do for testing:

- Make sure you test locally so you don't make big mistakes
- Use the [Reroute Email](http://drupal.org/project/reroute_email) module or another technique to make sure that email does not escape.
- Create dummy users with Devel Generate module (part of [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel))

Comment: I added detailed instructions. However, unless you don't need tokenized content you'll have to revert to an earlier version of VBO.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Mass Contact](http://drupal.org/project/mass_contact) module.

> The Mass Contact module allows anyone with permission to send a single message to multiple users of a site, using its roles functionality.

Comment: +1 looks good, but it requires me to do some parsing on my end :-(    Let's hope that I find an example in the docuentation

Comment: This worked great for me! It wasn't well documented at all, but the module does have a "config" link, and on the config page it tells you that the URL for the mass contact page is /mass_contact .