# Send emails to users

Tags: 6, emails

I want to send email to the users of my site, individually or to all of them  at once.
Is there any available module?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/how-can-i-email-all-registered-users check this

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Mass Contact](http://drupal.org/project/mass_contact) module it will match your requirement.

> The Mass Contact module allows anyone with permission to send a single
>   message to multiple users of a site, using its roles functionality.

or

The [Advanced User](http://drupal.org/project/advuser) Module allows users who have "administer users" permission to send mail to selected groups of users, and that includes selection by role.

Answer (score 1):

For an overview and comparion of Drupal newsletter modules, see this page on Drupal.org: [Comparison of email newsletter oriented modules](http://drupal.org/node/645108).

For an advanced solution that let you send  HTML-styled newsletters, look at [Simple news](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews).  For a basic mass mailing module, my choice would be [Mass contact](http://drupal.org/project/mass_contact).