# Inform user with account creation email, for existing users to

Tags: users, emails

Is there a way(It doesn't matter if passwords need to be recreated/generated) to send all the users an email about there account being added to the website after they are already added?

Comment: does this help? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/how-can-i-email-all-registered-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be really interested in this idea too.  I'm making a website to contain and extend an existing registry and it would be great to set the whole thing up with all the members' details and then just send out a mass email containing each user's username and generated password when everything's put together...

I haven't tested it yet, but it could potentially be done:

1. Set up your users, ensuring 'Notify User' is unchecked and Status is 'Blocked'.  If you already have active users, block them (make sure no email goes out, check `admin/config/people/accounts`)
2. When you're ready to notify the users, go to `admin/people` and check all the blocked users, then user Bulk Options to Activate them (if there's a huge amount of users you might want to do a group at a time to save the server a bit...)
3. Individual emails should be sent out containing a 'one-time login', see `admin/config/people/accounts` and scroll down to E-mails and choose 'Account Activation' for the email which goes out.

I will give it a shot and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Just tested it, and it seems you're solution worked perfectly.

Comment: I have also now used it to successful effect!  Worth noting that you can also Block and then re-Activate a user to resend the email and one-time-login link.

Answer (score 1):

The [Account Reminder](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_reminder) module could probably handle this requirement. Available for D6 and D7. Offers the ability to schedule the email to a given number of days after the account was set up and, as you might guess from the name it is designed to remind users who have not logged in to their account to log in. Can also be configured to send several reminders every X days.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a module for that but I don't know it.
But I would use `hook_user_insert` in a custom module and intercept each user creation.
In this hook_user_insert I would invoke `drupal_mail`

Comment: Looks promising, going to take a look and see if i can do fix something myself. Thanx for pointing to the drupal_mail hook.

Answer (score 0):

[Mass Messaging](https://drupal.org/project/mass_messaging) will allow you to do that.

> This module allows you to send mass messages to users. To compose and
>   select recipients the Views module is used. This allows complex
>   selection queries setup by a administrator. The mapping of the view
>   fields and the subject, recipient, message body and the attachments is
>   done in the view. To send a message the view plus the arguments of the
>   view are put into a queue. The cron does then send the messages in the
>   background.